# Restore a Linux backup on virtual machine

Tags: linux, centos, vmware, restore

I have made a backup of my Linux OS in a `bacukp.tgz`, the OS is Centos 6.4.
Now I want to create a new VMWare virtual machine from it.

Do I first need to install Centos from CD or ISO, and then overwrite all the files with backup or is there any way I can directly start  with the backup?

This is what I used to do the backup:

```
tar cvpzf /TEMP_BACKUPS/backup.tgz \
  --exclude=/proc \
  --exclude=/lost+found \
  --exclude=/tmp \
  --exclude=/TEMP_BACKUPS \
  --exclude=/mnt \
  --exclude=/sys \
  / > /TEMP_BACKUPS/mylog.txt
```

Comment: Since you are using a virtualization tool(VMWare), the easiest way to backup  and restore is using the VM tool's snapshot feature (https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/preserve_snapshot_ws.html)

Comment: @number5 No the original server is on Amazon Ec2 and i want to make the local copy of that on my local computer with vmware

Comment: You can make an AWS AMI out of your EC2 instance, then using packer.io to convert it to VMWARE image

Comment: @number5 I have Amazom AMI but how can i download it

Comment: you can follow [this guide](http://preda.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/downloading-an-amazon-ec2-ami-to-local-drive/) to download your api, or you can learn to use http://www.packer.io/intro to download AMI and convert it to VMWARE image for you

Comment: If you just want to restore your tarball (as opposed to downloading an image), boot a live CD in your VM. Then you can make a filesystem, and extract the tarball. You'll have to do more work to get it to boot (at least update /etc/fstab, update initramfs, and install bootloader)